# How can my master.tex file find font files stored in a subfolder to my working directory?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I need to use the font Gotham Rounded, and have so far placed the eights font files (.otf) in my working folder, i.e. the folder containing my master.tex file. This works fine. When compiling my masterfile XeLatex produces a Pdf of my manuscript with the Gotham font.

However, if I move the eight font files to a subfolder ("myFonts") of my working folder, then XeLaTeX is not able to find them.

How do I tell XeLaTeX where I have placed my font files? Can I set the path to the font files somewhere, and how will the path look?

In my preable I have placed the following code for my font choise:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Gotham Rounded
\setmainfont[
BoldFont=GothamRnd-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont=GothamRnd-LightIta.otf,
BoldItalicFont=GothamRnd-BoldIta.otf,
]{GothamRnd-Light.otf}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Generally, adding `Path=./myFonts/,` to the options should work

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly  do I add the string "Path =./myFonts/ " ?

Comment: In the options to `\setmainfont`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the path. I also recommend a clearer syntax.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Gotham Rounded
\setmainfont{GothamRnd}[
  Path=./MyFonts/,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Light,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  ItalicFont=*-LightIta,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIta,
]
```

The `*` stands for the main argument to `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will test out your solution soon.

Comment: It works perfect!